# Assign an ID Value for Every Set of Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How can i generate an ID value for every set of duplicate records as seen in the second table with ID column? In other words, how can I let the first table to look like the second table using SQL query?

Assume that first name and last name in the first table can appear in duplicates.

Each first name and last name can have one or many purchase yr and cost.

The given image is just a sample. Total records in table 1 can reach thousands.

I'm using Oracle SQL.

Note: I'm working with one table only that is the first one. The second table is what I want.

Comment: Are you working with 2 tables or just 1? Are you looking for an UPDATE query to update the table or simply a SELECT query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the DENSE_RANK analytic function to assign ID's as below:

**EDIT**:

Simplified query to generate ID's.

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY First_Name, Last_Name) ID,
      t.*
FROM Table1 t;
```

**Reference**:

[DENSE_RANK on Oracle Database SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm#i1064409)

Comment: This is the right idea, but I have no idea why you are joining to another table.  The OP only mentions one table and the subquery basically solves his/her problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am not clear if the "second table" the OP refers to is simply the second screenshot or really a second table. I'll request the OP to clarify.

Comment: . . "how can I let the first table to look like the second table using SQL query".

Comment: I have now edited the query to simply generate ID's from Table1. Thank you for your feedback!